# Why Java Container in Kubernetes takes more Memory as Limits?

Tags: java, kubernetes

I am running different Java Containers in Kubernetes with OpenJDK 11.0.8 and Payara-Micro and Wildfly 20. Resources are defined as followed:

```
      resources:
        requests:
          memory: "512Mi"
        limits:
          memory: "1Gi"
```

OpenJDK is running with default memory settings which means a Heap Ratio of 25%.

So I assume that 1G is the upper limit of memory the container can consume. But after some days the upper limits are exceeded as the containers memory consumption increases slowly but steadily.  In particular, it is the Non-Heap memory which is increasing and not the heap memory.

So I have two questions: why is the non-heap memory increasing and why is the `container/jdk/gc` ignoring the container memory limits?

**Example Measurement**

This is some example data about the pod and the memory consumption to illustrate the situation.

POD information (I skipped irrelevant data here):

```
$ kubectl describe pod app-5df66f48b8-4djbs -n my-namespace

Containers:
  app:
...
    State:          Running
      Started:      Sun, 27 Sep 2020 13:06:44 +0200
...
    Limits:
      memory:  1Gi
    Requests:
      memory:  512Mi
...
QoS Class:       Burstable
```

Check Memory usage with kubectl top:

```
-$ kubectl top  pod app-5df66f48b8-4djbs -n my-namespace
NAME                             CPU(cores)   MEMORY(bytes)   
app-587894cd8c-dpldq             72m          1218Mi
```

Checking memory limit inside the pod:

```
[root@app-5df66f48b8-4djbs jboss]# cat /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.limit_in_bytes
1073741824
```

VM Flags inside the pod/jvm:

```
[root@app-5df66f48b8-4djbs jboss]# jinfo  -flags <PID>
VM Flags:
-XX:CICompilerCount=2 -XX:InitialHeapSize=16777216 -XX:MaxHeapSize=268435456 -XX:MaxNewSize=89456640 -XX:MinHeapDeltaBytes=196608 -XX:NewSize=5570560 -XX:NonNMethodCodeHeapSize=5825164 -XX:NonProfiledCodeHeapSize=122916538 -XX:OldSize=11206656 -XX:ProfiledCodeHeapSize=122916538 -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=251658240 -XX:+SegmentedCodeCache -XX:+UseCompressedClassPointers -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+UseSerialGC
```

Heap Info inside the POD/jvm:

```
[root@app-5df66f48b8-4djbs jboss]# jcmd <PID> GC.heap_info 
68:
 def new generation   total 78656K, used 59229K [0x00000000f0000000, 0x00000000f5550000, 0x00000000f5550000)
  eden space 69952K,  77% used [0x00000000f0000000, 0x00000000f34bfa10, 0x00000000f4450000)
  from space 8704K,  59% used [0x00000000f4cd0000, 0x00000000f51e7ba8, 0x00000000f5550000)
  to   space 8704K,   0% used [0x00000000f4450000, 0x00000000f4450000, 0x00000000f4cd0000)
 tenured generation   total 174784K, used 151511K [0x00000000f5550000, 0x0000000100000000, 0x0000000100000000)
   the space 174784K,  86% used [0x00000000f5550000, 0x00000000fe945e58, 0x00000000fe946000, 0x0000000100000000)
 Metaspace       used 122497K, capacity 134911K, committed 135784K, reserved 1165312K
  class space    used 15455K, capacity 19491K, committed 19712K, reserved 1048576K
```

VM Metaspace Info:

```
$ jcmd 68 VM.metaspace
68:

Total Usage - 1732 loaders, 24910 classes (1180 shared):
  Non-Class: 5060 chunks,    113.14 MB capacity,   104.91 MB ( 93%) used,     7.92 MB (  7%) free,     5.86 KB ( <1%) waste,   316.25 KB ( <1%) overhead, deallocated: 4874 blocks with 1.38 MB
      Class: 2773 chunks,     19.04 MB capacity,    15.11 MB ( 79%) used,     3.77 MB ( 20%) free,   256 bytes ( <1%) waste,   173.31 KB ( <1%) overhead, deallocated: 1040 blocks with 412.14 KB
       Both: 7833 chunks,    132.18 MB capacity,   120.01 MB ( 91%) used,    11.69 MB (  9%) free,     6.11 KB ( <1%) waste,   489.56 KB ( <1%) overhead, deallocated: 5914 blocks with 1.78 MB


Virtual space:
  Non-class space:      114.00 MB reserved,     113.60 MB (>99%) committed 
      Class space:        1.00 GB reserved,      19.25 MB (  2%) committed 
             Both:        1.11 GB reserved,     132.85 MB ( 12%) committed 



Chunk freelists:
   Non-Class:

 specialized chunks:   43, capacity 43.00 KB
       small chunks:   92, capacity 368.00 KB
      medium chunks: (none)
   humongous chunks: (none)
              Total:  135, capacity=411.00 KB
       Class:

 specialized chunks:   18, capacity 18.00 KB
       small chunks:   64, capacity 128.00 KB
      medium chunks: (none)
   humongous chunks: (none)
              Total:   82, capacity=146.00 KB

Waste (percentages refer to total committed size 132.85 MB):
              Committed unused:    128.00 KB ( <1%)
        Waste in chunks in use:      6.11 KB ( <1%)
         Free in chunks in use:     11.69 MB (  9%)
     Overhead in chunks in use:    489.56 KB ( <1%)
                In free chunks:    557.00 KB ( <1%)
Deallocated from chunks in use:      1.78 MB (  1%) (5914 blocks)
                       -total-:     14.62 MB ( 11%)


MaxMetaspaceSize: unlimited
CompressedClassSpaceSize: 1.00 GB

InitialBootClassLoaderMetaspaceSize: 4.00 MB
```

**Answer**

The reason for the high values was an incorrect output of the Metric data received from Project [kube-prometheus](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/kube-prometheus). After uninstalling the kube-projemet and installing instead the [metric-server](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server) all data was display correctly using kubctl top. It shows now the same values as docker stats. I do not know why kube-prometheus did compute wrong data. In fact it was providing the double values for all memory data. I will investigate in this issue.

Comment: How are you measuring this?

Comment: what does `cat /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.limit_in_bytes` in the pod say?

Comment: I added additional measurement data to give more insight

Comment: I updated the data once again. You can see that the memory.limit_in_bytes is correct (1Gi) but with kubectl top I can see that more memory is currently consumed by the container

Comment: unless you tag me with `@`, I have no idea you added something to you post. how do you know that off-heap memory grows beyond 1GB, btw?

Comment: @Eugene: see the output of `kubectl top  pod`. It states a memory usage of 1218Mi. And this  is not heap memory.

Comment: thank you, I somehow missed that. I read a few posts here on SO where people where complaining about the same thing, I am very inclined to say that `kubectl top  pod` is to "blame", that is reports the wrong figures.

Comment: I added my own answer. The reason was a wrong output generated by the kube-prometheus project